# JavaFX Controller not getting UI fields initialized

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a JavaFX project via Scene Builder.
I created quite a long FXML file (I am reporting only a snippet) and the associated controller. Furthermore, I wrote my Application class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("myfxml.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Popolamento dati Ambasciata");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1150.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.FXController">
    ...
<children>
        <Button id="addobject" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addobject" text="Add Object" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
        <TextField id="objectname" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
```

Controller:

```
public class FXController {

@FXML Button addobject;
@FXML TextField objectname;

@FXML
public void addobject() {
    objectname.getText();
}
}
```

}

The application starts correctly and the event handler is invoked, but when accessing the TextField objectname, it is null.
Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `fx:id` attribute instead of `id`.

If you look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution):

> Assigning an fx:id value to an element creates a variable in the document's namespace that can later be referred to by variable dereference attributes

Note you can still use the `id`attribute:

> Additionally, if the object's type defines an "id" property, this value will also be passed to the objects setId() method.

So in your case:

```
<Button fx:id="addobject" ... />
<TextField fx:id="objectname" ... />
```